# Conditionals issue

Tags: c, if-statement

Can somone please explain me this and maybe put in `if` format?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int a = 0, b = 1, c = 3;
  *((a) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shortest version is : `a = 3;`

Answer (score 5):

This is utterly convoluted code and one should never write such a thing. But let's disassemble it. It is an assignment, so we have a left and a right part of the `=` sign.

Let us start with the right part, the value that is getting assigned. You have `a ? b : c`. the *ternary* operator will evaluate to `b` if the expression `a` is true, otherwise the value will be `c`. So we can write this with regular expressions like so:

```c
int value;
if (a) {
  value = b;
} else {
  value = c;
}
```

Now we go to the left part, there we have `*((a) ? &b : &a)`. We should read it from the inside out. We got another ternary operator there, `(a) ? &b : &a`. If the expression `(a)` evaluates to true, then the value is `&b`, otherwise `&a`. So we can write this like so:

```c
int *pointer;
if (a) {
  pointer = &b;
} else {
  pointer = &a;
}
```

Now we can do the actual assignment like this:

```c
*pointer = value;
```

As Barmar points out, one can do further simplifications. Both the conditionals depend on the value of `a`, so we can collapse them to this *whole* code:

```c
int value;
int *pointer;
if (a) {
  value = b;
  pointer = &b;
} else {
  value = c;
  pointer = &a;
}
*pointer = value;
```

But it is still way to convoluted, we don't need all these variables. We can just do the assignment directly. Then we have this, Barmar's version:

```c
if (a) {
  b = b;
} else {
  a = c;
}
```

But since `b` is not marked `volatile` (or a C++ class), assigning `b` to itself does not have any effect. The first statement is not needed. So we can further simplify it to this:

```c
if (!a) {
  a = c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's equivalent to:

```
if (a) {
    b = b;
} else {
    a = c;
}
```

The first conditional `*((a) ? &b : &a)` sets the destination of the assignment; if `a` is true, it indirects through `&b`, otherwise it indirects through `&a`.

The second conditional `a ? b : c` specifies the source of the assignment; if `a` is true it reads from `b`, otherwise it reads from `c`.

Comment: In the absence of the initialization of `b`, the original code is not completely equivalent to the code in this answer. Taking the address of an object has some effects. It prevents the rule in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 from applying, which would make subsequent uses of `b` indeterminate rather than undefined, even if the `!a` branch is used.

Comment: I guess my language-lawyer-foo is not good enough to understand what you're saying. The conditional operator on the RHS never uses `b` when `!a`, so what difference does it make if it's indeterminate or undefined?

Comment: It is **subsequent** uses of `b` that are affected. If `b` is used later in the code without previously having been assigned a value, then the program may have behavior not defined by the C standard if the code is `if (a) { b = b; } else { a = c; }`. But, if the code is `*((a) ? &b : &a) = a ? b : c;`, then using `b` later does not directly have undefined behavior. It is just an indeterminate value. Then, if the implementation does not define any trap representations for `b`, then using `b` has some value but not undefined behavior.

Comment: Are you saying that the mere appearance of `&b` in the conditional expression has consequences, even if the code is never executed?

Comment: The rule in C 2018 6.3.2.1 2 is phrased in terms of whether the object “could have been declared with the `register` storage class”. This is a translation-time property: If the code contains any attempt to take the address of the object, it cannot be declared as `register`, even if the code can never be executed, as in `if (0) &x;`. So, yes, the mere appearance of `&b` in the code prevents the rule in 6.3.2.1 2 from applying.

Answer (score 0):

it is equivalent to:

```
a ?  (b = b) : (a = c);
```

example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int a,b,c;

int foo(void)
{
    a ?  (b = b) : (a = c);
}


int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/DHk6M6

Comment: It might be equivalent, but still pretty hard to read!